# Ограничение ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
$(function(){
    $('#my_form').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $that = $(this),
        formData = new FormData($that.get(0));

        $.ajax({
            url: $that.attr('action'),
            type: $that.attr('method'),
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json){
                var messageResp = new Array('ок','не ок','длинно'); 
                rel_q();
                $("#message").val("");$("#uploadImage").val("");
                var resultStat = messageResp[Number(json)];
                $("#resp").text(resultStat).show().delay(1500).fadeOut(800);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

есть скрипт, осуществляемый по клику. Если на эту кнопку кликнуть несколько раз подряд, то столько раз и произойдет этот запрос, тем самым `$("#message").val("");$("#uploadImage").val("");` еще не успеют выполниться.

Как поставить ограничение на срабатывание, чтобы не было дублей по случайному нажатию?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. beforeSend: блокируем кнопку или ставим флаг.
2. comlete: разблокируем кнопку или убираем флаг.

Примерчик [смотрим тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/2kr3cdvc/2/).

```
$('#my_form').on('submit', function(e){
    var sbmt = $(':submit',this);
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/handler.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            out.text('Данные отправили, кнопку заблокировали');
            sbmt.prop('disabled', true);            
        },
        complete: function(){
            sbmt.prop('disabled', false); 
            out.text('Запрос завершен, кнопка разблокирована');
        },
        success: function(data){
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @Deonis, да, а на сайте было в обоих местах true, исправил и заработало, благодарю.